# Android: how to get rid of extra space in ImageView's bounding box

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to merge a two ImageViews to make them look like as one, but there's bounding box that prevents them to be totally next to each other.

[image: ImageViews bounding box]

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plant" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/red_base" />
```

I tried setting padding and margin to 0 but it doesn't do it

Note: those two pictures that I used don't have a blank space around them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set below two properties
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

Comment: This works for the plant and I tried tweaking it a bit for the vase to scaleType="fitXY", It works perfect! Please try to update your answer. It's good. :)

Comment: Sorry i answered according to ur question. i cant change it though bt people who read it, they will understand ur comment. Thanks for accepting and upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

in android gives some default padding 8dp for view:

try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="-4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plant" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="-4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/red_base" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set top margin for the below image as -5 dp i.e.   `android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"`

Below is your updated code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*Updated margin to -25dp, just to observe the change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) property of the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Push them to relative layout and place them manually, some thing like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plant" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/red_base" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dimension "180" in attribute "layout_marginTop" is missing unit!

Comment: @Brontok tnx, next time don't be lazy and edit it yourself ;)

Comment: Removed extra line :)